# thermocompression bond

Tags: verbs, vocabulary, writing-style

I want to use a verb for "perform thermocompression bonding." I have used "thermocompression bond" with/without a hyphen in the past as in "The component is typically thermocompression-bonded to the substrate." Are there any improvements?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thermocompression-bonded%22

Comment: As can be seen by searching, few people have used "thermocompression bond" as a verb, which is why I'm seeking possible alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks slightly awkward since *thermocompression* is such a long composite word.

It becomes clearer with easier examples:

"perform *laser cutting*"
The sample is *laser cut* from the substrate.

"perform frequency resolution"
The signal is frequency resolved.

All these sound right, don't they? I should be surprised however, if the hyphen were correct. At least in the journals I published this would not be hyphenated. In any case, stay consistent with those.

If you want to avoid it all together, perhaps paraphrasing might help?
"The component is bonded to the substrate with a thermocompression method."

"Thermocompression is typically used to bond the component to the substrate."

Comment: Have you checked anywhere?